# ElasticSearch C# NEST - How to prevent overwriting a document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When I perform an Index call, is there a way to make the call fail if a document with the same ID already exists?

I see warnings being issued, but the original document is still overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `_create` endpoint, or by specifying `OpType.Create` when indexing the document

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

// using OpType.Create
client.Index(new Test { Id = 1, Message = "message 1" }, i => i
    .OpType(OpType.Create)
);

// using _create endpoint
client.Create(new Test { Id = 1, Message = "message 1" });
```

If the document already exists, a HTTP 409 Conflict response will be returned. In both cases, you need an ID for the document that you're indexing/creating.

Comment: Is there something similar for IndexMany where it would skip the documents that already exist?

Comment: Not skip, but return a 409, yes. `IndexMany` is just a convenience around the `_bulk` API that exposes, There are Bulk Create, Update, Index and Delete operations. Check out the  Bulk API tests for different operation examples: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Tests/Document/Multiple/Bulk/BulkApiTests.cs#L74-L89